# celery celerybeat not ticking

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

I have the following setup:

```
celery-with-redis - 3.0        - active 
celery          - 3.0.12       - active 
django-celery   - 3.0.11       - active
django-kombu    - 0.9.4        - active
kombu           - 2.5.8        - active
redis           - 2.4.10
```

my celery settings are as follows:

```
BROKER_URL = "redis://:password@localhost:6379/0"
REDIS_DB = 0
REDIS_CONNECT_RETRY = True
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS=True
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="redis://:password@localhost:6379/0"
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES =  10
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER="djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
```

Checking my celerybeat log file it has the following

```
<ModelEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup(*[], **{}) {<crontab: * 4 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>}>
<ModelEntry: testing  spider.tasks.downloadCEA(*[], **{}) {<crontab: 4 9 * * * (m/h/d/dM/MY)>}>
[2013-04-02 09:16:15,364: DEBUG/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 seconds
```

But, it is not waking and sleeping as expected in the log file, also task changes modified via the admin interface were also not reflected in the log file. However, when i restarted redis, the appropriate behavior came back.

Can Anyone advise on this?

Update:
I did a quick `top` check on my redis process -  it was consuming 100% cpu usage! anyone?

Comment: Can't tell what's wrong from the info provided...

Comment: @Ngenator, my redis was consuming 100% CPU cycles.

Comment: Is redis running as a daemon? Check the logs. My guess is that it is having trouble saving the data to disk. It has a tendency to try repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, gonna answer my question here.

Turns out I was using a older version of kombu, and lots of connections to redis was created from the workers. Upgrading issue to a later version solved the issue.

this issue was described [here](https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/178) by @asksol.